# Show the pickadate calendar in the HTML document and not as a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, calendar

Is it possible to show the [pickadate](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/) calendar as part of the HTML document rather than as a popup dialog?

Currently an element (input or button) has to be clicked in order to show it as a popup dialog. I want to render it as part of my HTML view.

Comment: have you tried something so far?

Comment: Yes, but the plugin does not support it via API. So I am asking for some possible hacks.